# Acessar XML Retornado do WebService

Tags: delphi, web-service

Eu estou usando o `delphi seattle` para desenvolver um app e acessar um `webservice asmx/Soap`, e que o retorno dos métodos é em xml.

Eu consigo acessar todos os métodos do webservice e já testei no `Soapui`, onde consigo ver a resposta do xml, que no caso tem 3 itens, só que o retorno que estou tendo no delphi é uma classe `"UsuarioRetorno"` do tipo `TRemotable`.

Como faço para acessar essa classe `"UsuarioRetorno"` e ter acesso aos dados do xml? Ou se for o caso converter ela. Eu não consigo entender como usar essa classe de retorno, pq no doc gerado só tem isso:

```
AutenticarUsuarioResult = class(TRemotable) private
```

O que eu fiz no delphi para acessar os métodos foi:

```
(HTTPRIOAutenticar as ServiceSoap).Autenticar(dados1.Text, dados2.Text, "");
```

O método usado nesse caso é o autenticar.

Comment: você gerou as internfaces pelo WSDL importer?